# NR filter_chain_not_found when connecting to Nodejs TLS server using istio

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

I created a node js TLS server, dockerized it, and created a K8S Deployment and ClusterIP service for it. I created a DNS for the LoadBalancer service external IP of istio-ingressgateway and I’m using this DNS to try access this TLS server using istio but for some reason this error appears

```
[2022-02-10T04:28:38.302Z] "- - -" 0 NR filter_chain_not_found - "-" 0 0 3087 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 10.120.22.33:7070 10.101.31.172:44748 - -
```

The node server.js file:

```
const tls = require("tls");
const fs = require("fs");

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("server-key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("server-cert.pem"),

  rejectUnauthorized: false,
};
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
  console.log(
    "server connected",
    socket.authorized ? "authorized" : "unauthorized"
  );
  socket.write("welcome!\n");
  socket.setEncoding("utf8");
  socket.pipe(socket);
});
server.listen(7070, () => {
  console.log("server bound");
});
```

The client.js file I use to connect to the server:

```
const tls = require("tls");
const fs = require("fs");

const options = {
  ca: [fs.readFileSync("server-cert.pem", { encoding: "utf-8" })],
};
var socket = tls.connect(
  7070,
  "HOSTNAME",
  options,
  () => {
    console.log(
      "client connected",
      socket.authorized ? "authorized" : "unauthorized"
    );
    process.stdin.pipe(socket);
    process.stdin.resume();
  }
);
socket.setEncoding("utf8");
socket.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

socket.on("end", () => {
  console.log("Ended");
});
```

The cluster service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodejs-service
  namespace: nodejs-tcp
spec:
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 7070
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7070
  selector:
    app: nodejs
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

The istio-gateway.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: nodejs-gw
  namespace: nodejs-tcp
spec:
  selector:
    istio: istio-ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - 'HOSTNAME'
    port:
      name: tls
      number: 7070
      protocol: TLS
    tls:
      credentialName: tls-secret
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
```

In credentialName, I created a generic secret that holds the values of the private key and the certificate of the server

The istio-virtual-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nodejs-vs
  namespace: nodejs-tcp
spec:
  gateways:
  - nodejs-gw
  hosts:
  - 'HOSTNAME'
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 7070
      sniHosts:
      - HOSTNAME
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nodejs-service
        port:
          number: 7070
```

The Istio version I’m using:

```
client version: 1.12.2
control plane version: 1.12.2
data plane version: 1.12.2 (159 proxies)
```

Your help is so much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see [this issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/30819)?

Comment: Yes tried this solution but didn't work as well

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes I set up my clusters on GCP

Comment: @KareemYasser was the answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed right away is that you are using the incorrect selector in your `istio-gateway`, it should be:

```
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
```

A good troubleshooting starting point would be to get the routes for your `ingressgateway` and validate that you see the expected ones.

1. First you need to know your pod's name:

```
kubectl get pods -n <namespace_of_your_app>
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/my-nginx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx   2/2      Running   0          50m
```

In my deployment, it is an nginx pod.

2. Once you have the name, you can get the routes specific to your hostname:

```
istioctl pc routes <your_pod_name>.<namespace>
NOTE: This output only contains routes loaded via RDS.
NAME                                                          DOMAINS                               MATCH                  VIRTUAL SERVICE
my-nginx.default.svc.cluster.local:443                        my-nginx                              /*
```

This is an output example for a hostname "my-nginx". If the output returns no route, it usually means that it does not match SNI and/or cannot find a specific route.